# Variable length data in tcp socket in C

Tags: c, sockets

I want to create server that can handle variable length of data. For that I wrote following.

**Server:**

```
char buffer[256];

flush(buffer);
printf("Message: ");
while((n = read(sockfd ,buffer, 255)) > 0) {
    printf("%s", buffer);
    flush(buffer);
}
```

**Client:**

```
char buffer[512] = 'a' 366 times;

n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
```

But server continues in loop and does not exit. Do I need to send some specific character to server at the end of message from client? or condition of server loop need to be changed ?

Comment: You should be aware of what strlen() does.  You should read what TCP does.  You should be aware of how C strings work.

Comment: You should always `memset` your buffers to 0, because what Martin said is true! Because, mostly your stack-allocated buffer will contain garbage, where `strlen` is looking for terminating `\0`.

Comment: `flush` in snippet does the same as `memset`.

Comment: I am talking about the client-side code!

Comment: Thanks bash.d   Code shown in question is just sample and not actual code. So I haven't mentioned flush() function in that. But actually I'm using it.

Comment: @nouney Sorry for that but solution I have provided in comment of your answer was having bug. So I'm still working on it.

Comment: @Ravi What kind of bug ? Btw, the client-side code isn't correct (with your new solution of checking a null char): `strlen` doesn't count the null char, so it will not be sent (then the server-side code will not work)

Comment: @nouney. True. So, client need to send some different character rather than NULL to terminate the message. Now it is possible that the same character can be part of the message as well. At that time it will fail.

Comment: You can send the null char ! Just do this: `write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1);`, then the null char will be sent too.

Comment: I have changed server side loop as:
    `while((n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255)) > 0) {
        printf("%s\n", budder);
        len = strlen(buffer);
        if(len < 255 && buffer[len] == '\0')
            break;
        flush(buffer, 256);
    }`
    
And client side code as
    `n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer) + 1);`

And this looks working

Answer (score 0):

`read` will return 0 if `sockfd` is disconnected, or -1 if an error occured.
Actually, it's not an infinite loop : `read` will block the programm until there's new data available on `sockfd`.

You have to change your loop condition. For example you can send a specific char, and if its is the `recv`'s `buffer`, you stop the loop.

By the way, if you want to print `buffer`, you have to put a null character at its end:

```
char buffer[256];

flush(buffer);
printf("Message: ");
while((n = read(sockfd ,buffer, 255)) > 0) {
    buffer[n] = '\0';
    printf("%s", buffer);
    flush(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed server side loop as:

```
while((n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255)) > 0) {
    printf("%s", buffer);
    len = strlen(buffer);
    if(len < 255 && buffer[len] == '\0')
        break;
    flush(buffer);
}
```

And client side code as

```
n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1);
```

And this looks working

Comment: Ok great ! Don't forget that it will work only for non-binary data ;) (due to the null char delimiter)

Comment: Thanks @nouney. Right now I'm creating application for text data only.